# Visual Studio 2008 - name with more than one visit. I need an expression to count a distinct name ID on a date

Tags: date, reporting-services, visual-studio-2008, expression, distinct

I have a Visual Studio 2008 report with name, nameID, date of service, DOB and several other columns.  I need to count the distinct name (using the name ID) visits (date of service).  Some names have more than one date of service with more than 1 transaction (names=30, datesvc=36, transactions=80).
They are grouped by Name, NameID (hidden), DateSvc, Transaction.
I thought Count(DateSvc) would work but it gives me the same amount of transactions, not visits.
Any help is appreciated.

[image: Design View]

I cant put a sample of the data due to confidentiality.  But here's a typed sample of it:
Name......Date......DOB......More columns
DOB to the right can be several rows depending on the transaction
Service Date can span one or several rows depending on the date of the transaction
The name spans all rows for that persons transactions on the specific service date
Name.....1/1/16.....9/5/2008.....trans 1 for that day
...............1/4/16.....9/5/2008.....trans 1 for that day (same person)
...............1/4/16.....9/5/2008.....trans 2 for that day (same person)
Name.....6/9/16.....3/7/2002.....trans 1 for that day
Name.....6/9/16.....5/1/2000.....trans 1 for that day
This should show 3 names, 4 visits and 5 transactions
The 4 visits is where I'm having the problem.
Or a Snippet of the above but with data deleted out:
[image: Snippet of report info]

I hope this gives more clarity.

Comment: Did you try `=CountDistinct(Fields!DatesSvc.Value,"NameID")`? NameID is the group name in the row groups pane.

Comment: I keep getting this: The Value expression for the text box 'TextBox256' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region or the name of a dataset.

Comment: You said there is a group on NameID, what is the name of that group in SSRS?, you have to use it as the second parameter to countdistinct function.

Comment: My Row Groups shows FulName, tabbed in is NameID, tabbed in is DateSvc, tabbed in is TransID

Comment: If you provide a sample of your dataset and a screenshot of the tablix you are trying, we could help you more accurate.

Comment: I'm sorry but its been quite a while since I've been on StackOverflow.  How do I add a screenshot?

Comment: [How to upload an image](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) could help you while editing your question.

Comment: Are you trying to get the count of visits outside the tablix or what is the cell where you're placing the count expression?

Comment: I'm placing the expression in a separate tablix above the table.  I want that information (totals) separate and if the user wants to see the details, they can click to toggle and see the info below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example you put in your question I built a tablix with the following expressions:

[image]

**Total Names:** `=CountDistinct(Fields!Name.Value)` 
**Total Visits:** `=CountDistinct(Fields!Name.Value & "-" & Fields!Date.Value)` 
**Total Transactions:** `=Count(Fields!Record.Value)`

In your case `Record` should be `MedicalRecordNum` and `Name` should be `PatientID` instead of the name to avoid counting people with the same name.

The result is:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @TheOneNOnlyQ, Sure, `CountDistinct` counts the different names in your dataset, that is simple, as you need to count the different visits in different dates, I just concatenated Name and Date, for example `Amanda9/28/16` and passed it to CountDistinct function so it will count each patient in each different date. Hope it be clear for you.

Comment: YOU Alejandro are The Man! Yes that worked.  A Complex Expression:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220516.aspx#Anchor_2  Thanks a lot!!!